# Colored Octomaps

Tags: slam, navigation, octomap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There used to be an experimental octomap stack that allowed the user to generate colored octomaps. Does anyone still know how to access this and install it?

The only information I can find is in the post:
http://answers.ros.org/question/12883/problems-building-and-using-octomap-with-rgbdslam/
Apparently the a tar ball is no longer available that was downloaded by the makefile of the experimental stack. However, from felix's post it looks like it is possible to get this working again since the octomap library should have support for the colored octomaps.

Has anyone tried and/or succeeded at this?

PS I am currently running fuerte and can generate octomaps without the color information. It would be awesome if I could get them in color!

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45836/colored-octomaps/) by [P.Naughton](https://answers.ros.org/users/2954/p.naughton/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-10-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
the "official" octomap-server is - in principle - able to store colors (at least there is ColorOcTree.h), yet it lacks the color-octomap-server node. This was not trivial to port to the most recent ROS versions. I have recently integrated the octomap library into rgbdslam, so one doesn't need the octomap server anymore, but can save colored octomaps directly from rgbdslam. However, I need to get the whole source base in a reasonable state before releasing the next version. This might take a while (end of this year?).

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0